# Magento error 500 on products

Tags: php, magento

I'm having problems with some products on my magento website, V1.7.02.

When I access those pages I get an error 500. The only way I see it's an error 500 is with chrome debugger tools which shows a network error. On the screen I only get a blank screen.

Tried to enable error reporting on screen with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

inside the index file, but nothing.

Tried to enable loggin but it's not written into the exeption/system logs (other things does).

Tried to duplicate one of these products and the copy also creates the same error - New products seems to work.

I simply have no idea on how to tackle this...
Any idea will be greatly appreciated.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

This following link would be helpful for you to set it in developer mode :

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/

Answer (score 1):

1) Turn on your logging: Admin

> Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes

2) Watch your var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log for raw information from this.

Ref url :- http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tips-tricks/magento-error-logs/#

Comment: @Yanipan, have you got solution ?, it's work or not ?, try once with clear ur all Cache,